# WinError 10600 timeout happening when doing running socket.connect in Python

Tags: python, windows, sockets

So I'm running socket.connect in Python to connect to a server like so (some parts removed cuz proprietary info):

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    self.sock.connect(("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", XXXX))
except socket.timeout:
    DO_SOMETHING
```

Anyway what's weird is that this only works like 1 out of 10 times.  9 out of 10 times I get an error saying:

"TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

I'm pretty sure I have the network configuration right for both server/client.  The fact that it randomly works fine 1 out of 10 times seems to reinforce this.  I think the problem is just timing.  I think maybe 1 out of 10 times the timeout just so happens to happen after the server responds.

Anyway, I can't change how the server works in my case.  Also changing the timeout fields of the socket object in Python does nothing to change this timeout (the timeout stays at a couple seconds, I want to change it to something much longer).  This timeout seems to be some lower level Windows thing.  Does anyone know how I would change the timeout related to WinError 10060?

Comment: Show us how you "changed the timeout fields of the socket object". If that appears not to work then maybe you didn't do it quite right.

Comment: I just did self.sock.settimeout(3600) right after the line I created the socket.  I took it out though because it didn't seem like it was doing anything.

Comment: Maybe this will help you solve the problem: https://serverfault.com/q/193160/5590371